# Configuring Environment Variables to resolve version mismatch while running cake script

Tags: .net, powershell, webforms, cakebuild

I am new to the cake script. 
I am trying to run an existing cake script that is already developed. 
It is throwing following an error.

```
Cake.exe : Error: The assembly 'MagicChunks.Cake, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' 
At line:1 char:1
+ & "Y:\Source\Repos\CI\tools\Cake\Cake.exe" "build.cake" -target="Defa ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Error: The asse...KeyToken=null' :String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

is referencing an older version of Cake.Core (0.23.0). 
This assembly must reference at least Cake.Core version 0.26.0. 
Another option is to downgrade Cake to an earlier version. 
It's not recommended, but you can explicitly opt out of assembly verification 
by configuring the Skip Verification setting to true
(i.e. command line parameter "--settings_skipverification=true", 
environment variable "CAKE_SETTINGS_SKIPVERIFICATION=true", 
read more about configuration at https://cakebuild.net/docs/fundamentals/configuration)
```

can anyone tell me where should I have to configure the environment variables to avoid above mentioned error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NOTE**: Corrected based on comments from @PascalBerger.

MagicChunks.Cake is reaching back for a specific version of an assembly, but finding an newer version. You'd like to disregard the version check by leveraging the guidance:

> It's not recommended, but you can explicitly opt out of assembly verification 
>   by configuring the Skip Verification setting to true
>   (i.e. command line parameter "--settings_skipverification=true", 
>   environment variable "CAKE_SETTINGS_SKIPVERIFICATION=true"

You can set an environment variable a few different ways...

```
## Powershell
[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('CAKE_SETTINGS_SKIPVERIFICATION', 'true',[System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine)
```

Using the Windows UI,

1. Right-click the Windows menu (lower left of the screen).
2. Select **System** from the context menu.
3. Click the **System Info** link.
4. Click the **Advanced Settings** link.
5. On the Advanced tab, click **Environment Variables...**
6. Add your environment variable.

Comment: HI @Adam Thanks for the response, if you see the error, it says to configure environmental variables to skip the verification using the command line

Comment: Lol! I get it. Wouldn't you set it like any other env-variable? `[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('CAKE_SETTINGS_SKIPVERIFICATION', 'true',[System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine)`

Comment: @Adam It's the other way round. MagicChunks.Cake is still targeting Cake 0.23.0. So solution is to downgrade Cake to 0.23.0 (not upgrade) or suppress the warning through the command line parameter or the environment variable as mentioned in your previous comment.
Note that addin _might_ be broken if it has been built against an incompatible API, therefore the warning. It depends on the API which the specific API uses (in case of MagicChunks.Cake I _think_ it should still work with latest version of Cake)